# in jquery using checkbox get li attr

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, checkbox

I want to get data of li using checkbox. in my code you can see checkboxes and list of songs ... i want when checkbox is checked and click on button .get  all the checked li attr.

using jquery, when user checked checkboxes and click on button. i want to get

attr as like song , cover and artist.

as same like [this site](http://www.apunkabollywood.us/in/search/?by=song&keyword=papuyaar&start=60)

```
 <table>
        <ul id="playlist" class="hidden">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="check_1" name="check_1" id="check_1"></td>
                <td><li id="songlist" song="Bhai Nirmal Singh Ji - Apne Har Peh Benti.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Linkin Park">Bhai Nirmal Singh Ji - Apne Har Peh Benti.mp3</li></td>
                <td><a href="" id="add">Add to Cart</a></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="check" name="check"></td>
                <td><li id="songlist" song="Linkin Park - One Step Closer.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Linkin Park">One Step Closer.mp3</li></td>
                <td><a href="" id="add">Add to Cart</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="check" name="check"></td>
                <td><li song="Linkin Park - With You.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Linkin Park">With You.mp3</li></td>
                <td><a href="">Add to Cart</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="check" name="check"></td>
                <td><li song="Linkin Park - Points Of Authority.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Linkin Park">Points Of Authority.mp3</li></td>
                <td><a href="">Add to Cart</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="check" name="check"></td>
                <td><li song="Linkin Park - Crawling.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Linkin Park">Crawling.mp3</li></td>
                <td><a href="">Add to Cart</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="check" name="check"></td>
                <td><li song="Linkin Park - Runaway.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Linkin Park">Runaway.mp3</li></td>
                <td><a href="">Add to Cart</a></td>
            </tr>

        </ul>

    </table>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: have you tried something yourself?

Comment: (Sidenote) HTML5 conventions for custom attributes would be `data-song="..."`, `data-cover="..."` instead of just `song="..."`, `cover="..."`.

Comment: Kartikeya is right. You have to try something, show us your code if you're stuck, so we can help you. You can't just basically ask "Could you please do this for me?"

Comment: no i have no idea how to do this . but i do this in simple way. on click all list played

Comment: `function initAudio(element){
 var song = element.attr('song');
    var title = element.text();
    var cover = element.attr('cover');
    var artist = element.attr('artist');

 //Create a New Audio Object
 audio = new Audio('media/' + song);
 
 if(!audio.currentTime){
  $('#duration').html('0.00');
 }

 $('#audio-player .title').text(title);
    $('#audio-player .artist').text(artist);
 
 //Insert Cover Image
 $('img.cover').attr('src','images/covers/' + cover);
 
 $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');
}
`

Comment: Your html format is wrong, so, at first change your html in right syntax.

Comment: ok thanks  .. i will try to do , but i want just idea how to get li attr on checked checkbox

Comment: Yep, `table > ul > tr` ... wooops... Either use `ul > li` (list), or `table > tr > td` (table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way:**  *update*

```js
$(window).load(function() {

  $(".add,#play_button").click(function() {
    var selected_items = $("#playlist tr td input:checked");

    if (selected_items.length == 0) {
      alert("item is not selected");
    } else {

      var song = [];
      var cover = [];
      var artist = [];
      selected_items.each(function() {
        song.push($(this).data("song"));
        //semilerly following
        //cover.push($(this).data("cover"));
        //artist.push($(this).data("artist"));


      })
      alert(song);
    }
  });
  $("#selectall").click(function() {
    var c = this.checked;
    $("#playlist :checkbox").prop("checked", c);
  });
  $("#selectall_button").click(function() {
    var c;
    if ($(this).val() == "Select All") {
      c = true;
      $(this).val("Deselct All");
    } else {
      c = false;
      $(this).val("Select All");
    }

    $("#playlist :checkbox").prop("checked", c);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="playlist">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-song="Bhai Nirmal Singh Ji - Apne Har Peh Benti.mp3" data-cover="cover1.jpg" data-artist="Linkin Park" name="check[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      Bhai Nirmal Singh Ji - Apne Har Peh Benti.mp3
    </td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add">Add to Cart</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-song="Bhai  Ji - Apne" data-cover="cover1.jpg" data-artist="Linkin Park" name="check[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      Bhai Nirmal Singh Ji - Benti.mp3
    </td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add">Add to Cart</a>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="selectall" />select all/deselect all
<input type="submit" id="selectall_button" value="Select All" />
<input type="submit" id="play_button" value="Play selected" />
```

Comment: one think which i want is that if i check all the checkboxes then show all the song name on click another button

Comment: @harvinder  Then the inner code of this function add into your another button click function

Comment: no, i want button at bottom and when check multiple chechbox , click on button , alert all the name of songs which are checked .

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly then you wish to get the song and cover from the the `li` if the checkbox is checked, i also changed the class of your links so i can easily find them with jQuery

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nniicc/aqxcxqvh/)

Comment: I forgot to mention that i have changed the class of your link so i can find them with jQuery

Comment: one think which i want is that if i check all the checkboxes then show all the song name on click another button

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's how I'd do it :

```js
$("button").click( function(){
  
  var selection = [];
  
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked:enabled").each( function(){ // Selects checked checkboxes and loops through them
    
      selection.push({
          "title"  : $(this).attr("data-title"),
          "artist" : $(this).attr("data-artist")
      
       })
    
  })
  
  $("#results").html(JSON.stringify(selection));
  
  console.log(selection);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>
     <input type="checkbox" data-title="song 1" data-artist="Artist 1" /> Song 1
   </li>
  
   <li>
     <input type="checkbox" data-title="song 2" data-artist="Artist 2" /> Song 2
   </li>
  
  <li>
     <input type="checkbox" data-title="song 3" data-artist="Artist 3" /> Song 3
   </li>
</ul>

<button>Get checked songs</button> <br>
<br>
<p id="results"></p>
```

Now "selection" is a array of objects, each object containing one title, one artist, etc.

Store your data in the checkboxes directly, why add difficulty by storing them in a different element?

Comment: i want just like this but li attr on checkbox click

Comment: I don't know why, as it is just a bit more complicated, but in that case, you can go `$(this).parent()` which will give you the `li` instead of the `checkbox`.